# If alt is empty, get caption or title of the Wordpress image

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function that returns the caption of the image or the title of the image in the alt of the images in the posts if I don't have the alt attribute defined. The function is below, but it is not working. What can be happening?

```
function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {
    
    if ( ( is_single() || is_page() ) && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {

        $attachments= get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );

        foreach( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {

            $alt_image = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );

            // If the ALT of the image is empty, get other information from the attachment
            if ( empty( $alt_image ) )
                $attachment = get_post( $attachment->ID );
            
            // Use caption if you don't have ALT
            if ( empty( $alt_image ) )
                $alt_image = $attachment->post_excerpt;
            
            // Use image title if you do not have an ALT or caption
            if ( empty( $alt_image ) )
                $alt_image = $attachment->post_title;
        }
    }
 
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop', -1 );
```

Comment: this functions seems to do nothing because you pass $content and return it without modifing it. How do you call the function? what are you doing with it? bigger example needed! You have to simplify the function and try from little to bigger ;)

Comment: You're also not parsing any of the $post data to the function so there's nothing it can really do. What is the $content? If that's should be used instead of $post, then you still need to either alter $content before it's returned or return your $alt_image instead, depending on how the rest of your code works.